# Can anyone help in adding partial file name option in this code

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I have a code which is perfect and can copy/move a specific file based on excel list with partial file name option.

However the only problem is that it only copies 1 file at a time (if the starting file names are same). Is there is any possible way where if i run the code it should copy/move all the files if there are more than 1 files where starting file names are same as well. Your cooperation will be highly appreciated.

```vb
Sub CopyFilesFromListPartial()
    
    Const sPath As String = "E:\Asianet2"
    Const dpath As String = "E:\Asianet\EMIS"
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As String = "A"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    ' Calculate the last row,
    ' i.e. the row containing the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
                 
    ' Early Binding - needs a reference
    ' to 'Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime' (has intelli-sense)
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    ' Late Binding - needs no reference (no intelli-sense)
    'Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Validate the source folder path.
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = sPath
    If Right(sFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFolderPath = sFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The source folder path '" & sFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Validate the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = dpath
    If Right(dFolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then dFolderPath = dFolderPath & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(dFolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The destination folder path '" & dFolderPath _
            & "' doesn't exist.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim r As Long ' current row in worksheet column
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sPartialFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim dFilePath As String
    Dim sYesCount As Long ' source file copied
    Dim sNoCount As Long ' source file not found
    Dim dYesCount As Long ' source file exists in destination folder
    Dim BlanksCount As Long ' blank cell
    
    For r = fRow To lRow
        sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)
        If Len(sPartialFileName) > 3 Then ' the cell is not blank
            ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName
            sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")
            ' or instead, 'Contains' sPartialFileName
            'sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")
            If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found
                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
                    fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination
                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
                End If
            Else ' the source file doesn't exist
                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
        Else ' the cell is blank
            BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
        End If
    Next r


End Sub
```

Comment: It still copies 1 file at a time,

Comment: If there are 2 files where starting names are same it only copies 1 file

Answer (score 0):

The following tweak to your loop should cause all files that match each `sFileName` to be copied.

```
For r = fRow To lRow
    sPartialFileName = CStr(ws.Cells(r, Col).Value)
    If Len(sPartialFileName) > 3 Then ' the cell is not blank
        ' 'Begins with' sPartialFileName
        sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sPartialFileName & "*")
        ' or instead, 'Contains' sPartialFileName
        'sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*" & sPartialFileName & "*")
        Do While sFileName <> ""
            If Len(sFileName) > 3 Then ' source file found
                sFilePath = sFolderPath & sFileName
                dFilePath = dFolderPath & sFileName
                If Not fso.FileExists(dFilePath) Then ' the source file...
                    fso.CopyFile sFilePath, dFilePath ' ... doesn't exist...
                    sYesCount = sYesCount + 1 ' ... in the destination
                Else ' the source file exists in the destination folder
                    dYesCount = dYesCount + 1
                End If
            Else ' the source file doesn't exist
                sNoCount = sNoCount + 1
            End If
            sFileName = Dir
        Loop
    Else ' the cell is blank
        BlanksCount = BlanksCount + 1
    End If
Next r
```

However, you may need to adjust your counts to get them to still accurately account for how many files were copied/failed/non-existent.

Comment: Dear Sir, I would like to thank you so much that this tweak is now working perfectly as required,  Now can  you please advise what if the destination  folders are more than 1. Currently what i did is i have added a Module 2 and added second folder destination in  it but it is a lengthy process as i have to add 11 more destination folders. is there any way.    Also if you could remove the dialogue box which appears after code running it will be wonderful.. thanks

Comment: For 1. - you'd need to raise another question. You'll need to fully explain what you want though, as it's unclear from the above how you'd expect to assign each file to which destination if there are 11 to choose from

Comment: For 2. - there is no dialogue box in your original code. I can only assume that wasn't pasted in. You need to locate it in your code (it will likely be a `MsgBox` command) and remove it yourself.

Comment: Removed Thank you, Hurrah

Comment: the code mentioned above is able to copy the files to one destination folder, whereas i have 15 destination folders where i need to copy the files specifically.  Currently, in order to copy specific files in more than 1 destination i have added more modules and now running them separately so that specific files can be copied to specific folders as needed. Can anyone help me by upgrading the code so that i can add more than one destination folders (upto 15) and if i run them once it can copy files (mentioned in Excel sheet coloumn A, B, C, etc) in the desired folders. Please

Comment: Hi @Salman - I'm sure myself or someone else could help - but you'll need to raise this as a new question. The existing question is answered (feel free to mark this as answered) and your new requirement should include the new code you're using and the full detail of what you now need.